# Cloning React elements with cloneWithProps

Tags: reactjs

The following code is from a React [tutorial](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/clone-with-props.html):

```jsx
var _makeBlue = function(element) {
  return React.addons.cloneWithProps(element, {style: {color: 'blue'}});
};

var Blue = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    var blueChildren = React.Children.map(this.props.children, _makeBlue);
    return <div>{blueChildren}</div>;
  }
});

React.render(
  <Blue>
    <p>This text is blue.</p>
  </Blue>,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

How does the line `React.Children.map(this.props.children, _makeBlue)` work?

`_makeBlue` is assigned a function with an argument `element` but it doesn't seem like any elements are passed into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this line:

```
var blueChildren = React.Children.map(this.props.children, _makeBlue);
```

`this.props.children` contains the elements—or, rather, component instances—passed to `_makeBlue`. In the case of the example, `this.props.children` will contain a single child: `<p>This text is blue.</p>`.